# How do I remove a categoriy of varible expression from a geom_density chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am putting together a geom_density to express drug use in a population along with an "Age" distribution. I would like to omit the "No" variable response (which is embedded with other answers in the column of N =597) from being expressed in the chart.

I've looked around at Boolean syntax possibilities but found no clear grammar examples to fit this context. I reviewed ? help documentation and could not locate a ready example on how to omit values from a chart.

```
drugs <- Substance_use_self_report

ggplot(drugs, aes(Age, fill = drug_of_choice)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.25)
```

In the `Drug_of_choice` column of my dataset, the field is overfitted with `No` response cells. I would like to omit those cells from being expressed in the chart. (So we can see what drugs people like, without the "no" blob in there!) :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `ggplot(drugs[drug_of_choice!="No",], ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do some filtering and pipe right into `ggplot()`

```r
set.seed(1234)
drugs <- 
  tibble(
    Age = sample(25:50, 60, replace = TRUE),
    drug_of_choice = c(rep("No", 20), sample(letters[1:3], 40, replace = TRUE))
  )

drugs %>% 
  filter(drug_of_choice != "No") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Age, fill = drug_of_choice)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.25)
```